# Is this the most accurate translation of 二つめの言葉は風　行くてを教えて?

Tags: translation

This sentence from a [song](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-35531.html)

> futatsume no kotoba wa kaze
>   yukute wo oshiete

it's translated as

> The second word was "wind"
>   directing my journey

Would you translate it the same? What would be the most literal translation?
What I get for the second line is this

The second word, wind
showing my way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, @virmaior, for linking the page. :)

> > そっと　連れだすの
> >
> > **ふたつめの言葉は風
> >
> >     行くてを　おしえて**
> >     神様の腕の中へ
> >     翼をあおるの
>
> The given translation: The second word was "wind" /  directing my journey "
>
> The OP's version: The second word, wind /  showing my way

The whole thing is written with the non-past, so I prefer it not with 'was', but we have something called 体言止め{たいげんどめ}, so I believe it's ok to consider ふたつめの言葉は風 as a complete sentence.

For 行くてを おしえて, I like yours much better. :)